# OAuth in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, foursquare

I am trying to learn Phonegap and make a small application using that for Andorid. My application needs to pull out nearby restaurants from the FourSquare API.

What are the various ways in which I can do this?

I could not understand the documentation of FourSqaure. It needs OAuth mechanism to be done. How can I do this in a PhoneGap application - lack of redirect URI.

It will be very helpful if someone can tell me which way to go and how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the ChildBrowser plugin? (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser)  I used it against Twitter and it seemed to work for authentication.  But you do have the problem of having to store your secret OAuth key in an easily accessible format.

Comment: Yes. I did that and I succeeded. ChildBrowser is the best way to do OAuth authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I was just struggling with the same problem earlier this month. I was looking for a good way to hit a custom RESTful service on Android. I came across this library, named Scribe (https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java). It works really well with Android. Better yet, it already has support for Foursquare OAuth built in! Here is the example file they show working with Scribe+Android+Foursquare:

```
package org.scribe.examples;

import java.util.Scanner;

import org.scribe.builder.*;
import org.scribe.builder.api.*;
import org.scribe.model.*;
import org.scribe.oauth.*;

public class FoursquareExample
{
  private static final String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL = "http://api.foursquare.com/v1/user";

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                            .provider(FoursquareApi.class)
                            .apiKey("FEGFXJUFANVVDHVSNUAMUKTTXCP1AJQD53E33XKJ44YP1S4I")
                            .apiSecret("AYWKUL5SWPNC0CTQ202QXRUG2NLZYXMRA34ZSDW4AUYBG2RC")
                            .build();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("=== Foursquare's OAuth Workflow ===");
    System.out.println();

    // Obtain the Request Token
    System.out.println("Fetching the Request Token...");
    Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
    System.out.println("Got the Request Token!");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Now go and authorize Scribe here:");
    System.out.println(service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken));
    System.out.println("And paste the verifier here");
    System.out.print(">>");
    Verifier verifier = new Verifier(in.nextLine());
    System.out.println();

    // Trade the Request Token and Verfier for the Access Token
    System.out.println("Trading the Request Token for an Access Token...");
    Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
    System.out.println("Got the Access Token!");
    System.out.println("(if your curious it looks like this: " + accessToken + " )");
    System.out.println();

    // Now let's go and ask for a protected resource!
    System.out.println("Now we're going to access a protected resource...");
    OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL);
    service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
    Response response = request.send();
    System.out.println("Got it! Lets see what we found...");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(response.getBody());

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Thats it man! Go and build something awesome with Scribe! :)");
 }

}
```

Comment: How do you redirect your user from your app to the authentication URL and then back to your application ?

Comment: Not sure if you saw this but Foursquare has some [example Android code](https://github.com/foursquare/android-oauth-example). If you want to handle the redirection, you can always do it in an embedded webview and then follow the [Pure AJAX approach](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth).

Comment: I am actually a newbie with mobile dev. How can I do that? I am using PhoneGap